# Sharepoint unique access

Tags: permissions

I recently created a sharepoint site for my project  I would like to just grant all access to any user without them having to request permission.  Basically I’d like to link it to the wiki so anyone can click it and read the content  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can give all authenticated users read access or turn on anonymous access.

Comment: okay thank you!! if we turn on anonymous access what access does user have?

Comment: Well, when you turn on anonymous for the web application, none.  You still have to enable it for each site.  For that site I typically enable it for the entire web site.  If you need to lock down any lists or libraries, you can still do that.